# How to make Scala implicits explicit in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala, implicit, scala-ide

According to "Programming in Scala" one can pass the argument -Xprint:typer to the compiler and gets the code back as it looks after all the implicites are actually applied.

I also found that I can set compiler arguments in the project properties.

But I can't find any resulting output anywhere ...

So where do I have to look?

Comment: You might want to ask at Scala IDE mailing list: http://groups.google.com/group/scala-ide-user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the Scala IDE 2.1 Milestone 1 you can press Ctrl-1 to make implicits explicit

From http://scala-ide.org/download/milestone.html#scala_ide_21_milestone_1

> Highlight Implicits It has never been easier to know where implicits
>   are applied. And, by pressing Cmd/Ctrl+1, turn an implicit conversion
>   into an explicit call!

Answer (score 2):

If you start Eclipse from a console, you should see the printed output there.

Comment: I tried to start eclipse.exe and eclipsec.exe Both don't create any output.

Comment: Hm, that's interesting; I'm on Linux and I get a lot of output to the console. Sorry :-/